# Is Godot's NavMesh viable for dynamic pathfinding (e.g. avoiding moving enemies)?

Tags: unity, path-finding, godot

I am a novice (read: low-budget) designer looking at moving from Pygame to a real engine, and between Unity and Godot it looks like the latter has a *much* better 2D engine [[1](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16674933), [2](https://medium.com/@rockmilkgames/why-godot-engine-e0d4736d6eb0), [3](https://www.slant.co/versus/1047/1068/~unity_vs_godot)]. I would be happy to support Godot's open-source model except that, as far as I can tell, its built-in navigation mesh is purely static--i.e. it can't update its path to account for dynamic obstacles [[4](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/4vgpn7/2d_pathfinding_collision_avoidance_milestone/), [5](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-create-2d-navigation-godot-engine-0/)]--while Unity's pathfinding system can [[6](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html)].

So my question is: Am I "stuck" with Unity? Or is there functionality that I haven't yet been able to find? Or, alternatively, is GDScript *significantly* faster than Python such that basic algorithms like fixed-grid A* would do the job?

Edit: By "stuck" with Unity I don't mean that it's a bad option or that there aren't good options; I mean, 'if I need good pathfinding, do I have to give up on Godot and use what would otherwise be a second-choice engine?'

Comment: Stuck with Unity? What about Unreal? I'm sure there are other options as well.

Comment: @Almo That was poorly worded; I meant more broadly "stuck" with something that's not Godot (which may turn out to be just as good). Edited.

Comment: This looks like a "which technology should I use" question. I think we could make this more constructive by focusing on "how can I achieve dynamic pathfinding in Godot?" - that way the answer isn't just yes or no; a positive answer should include a method to achieve that result. If you can present a concrete example of the pathfinding scenarios you need to solve in your game, that will help focus solutions on meeting those specific requirements.

Comment: @DMGregory That makes sense; I'll re-write and re-submit.

Comment: For anyone who finds this post in the future, Godot 4.0 will add a better navmesh system which allows for dynamic obstacles as well as baking the navmesh at runtime, along with a lot of other improvements.